# Differing parameters for Google Data Studio Connector to retrieve data

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to connect to a datastore that needs different parameters to retrieve the data.
I've tried different multiple instances of the data connector - but data studio seems to struggle to store different configuration values? The Data Connector control isn't currently available for community connectors.
What's the best approach please ?

Answer (score 2):

Community Connectors currently do not support parametrization. We have plans to add this feature in the future. At present, other than dates, you cannot pass parameters to the connector while viewing the dashboard.

You can add the same connector multiple times as separate data sources using different configurations or you can edit the current data source and change the parameters (under Manage data sources).

Comment: OK... I find that data studio doesn't do the "multiple instances" of the same connector well. Whether it caches the parameters or something I don't know but it proves hard to get multiple instances of the same connector each with different parameters in practice...

Comment: @VernonR: It would be helpful if you could [report a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=321382&template=0) with the exact problem you have been facing and steps to reproduce. User feedback is always appreciated!

Comment: I see the accepted issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66586053

Comment: @oshliaer That issue talks mentions dynamic parameters (one parameter's values are based on the selection in another parameter). However, OP's question was about parameterization which involes changing parameter selections form within the dashboard rather than from the config.