# Accessing report data (just like dateRange.dateStart)?

Tags: looker-studio

Is it possible to access a filter component's value when issuing getData calls?

```
function getData(request) {
  var requestedFieldIds = request.fields.map(function(field) {
    return field.name;
  });
  var requestedFields = getFields().forIds(requestedFieldIds);

  var url = [
    'https://api.endpoint.com/',
    request.dateRange.startDate,
    ':',
    request.dateRange.endDate,
    '/',
    request.???.reportComponentValue // this
  ];

  ...

}
```

I logged the getData **request** parameter after adding the filter component to the report, but it unfortunately doesn't have anything other than configParams, along with the value(s) defined when adding the connector - *"package": "npm"*.

> [19-01-10 08:45:08:637 EET] getData request:
>   {"configParams":{"package":"npm"},"dateRange":{"endDate":"2019-01-09","startDate":"2018-12-13"},"scriptParams":{"lastRefresh":"1547102707478"},"fields":[{"name":"downloads"},{"name":"packageName"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something similar was asked here: [Differing parameters for Google Data Studio Connector to retrieve data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972289/differing-parameters-for-google-data-studio-connector-to-retrieve-data)

Which referenced this google issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66586053

Meaning it's **currently not possible**. Someone said:

> If your issue already exists then please vote for it as most voted
>   issues are given higher priority. – Minhaz Kazi Nov 7 '17 at 16:30